# Violation of Symfony2 routing requirement does not lead to a response with the correct content type

Tags: php, routes, annotations, symfony

I'm currently writing a REST service within a Symfony2 application. This is (roughly) how one of my controllers look like:

```
/**
 * @Route("/account", defaults={"_format" = "json"})
 */
class AccountController extends APIController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/")
     * @Method("get")
     */
    public function listAction()
    {
        // process something here and return JSON-encoded response
    }
}
```

This works all fine - i.e. if some problem pops up and I throw a `HTTPException`, the correct `error.json.twig` from Symfony2's TwigBundle is used and renders the HTTP error as JSON.

However, this is not true for the violation of route requirements, of which `@Method("get")` is one. If I for example throw a `POST` or `PUT` against the above URL, I still get the correct HTTP status code back, but rendered with the wrong content-type (text/html instead of application/json).

I'm very much interested to let the complete API return JSON responses and nothing else - the question is: How do I achieve that? Do I have to omit route requirements alltogether and check the requirements myself (and then eventually throw my own `HTTPException`s)?

Answer (score 0):

You probably should file it as a bug/wish at their [github page](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues). (I've tried to locate the responsible PHP file, but the HttpKernel component is not exactly for the faint of heart.)

Comment: From what I've seen in the generated code a proper HTTPException is fired, but God (or Fabien) knows where exactly the format handling gets into the mix...

Answer (score 0):

You could always try using yml routing over annotation. Works fine for me. Sorry couldnt give a more helpful response.

Comment: I did all my routing with annotations, so it would be cool to stay that way.